# Headphones play very low music, voices are just whispers

Tags: audio, windows-10, speakers, headphones, tablet

My headphones are Sony MDR-G45.
I was listening to music on my speakers but the sound isn't as good as it is on headphones so I switched to my Sony's. Now everything is very low. It plays music but not loud enough (my sound is at 50 on my Dell tablet) and voices are nothing more than whispers. 
I've checked the jack and its not wibbly, the plug isn't wobbly and there's no rattle in the headphones, or buzzing. When I unplug it, all the sounds play fine on the speakers but not the headphones.
I tried a hard reset in case it was a glitch but that didn't help.
I have tried someones method of jiggling the plug a little as I plug it in but nothing changed. I also went to Playback Devices and made sure 'Do nothing.' was selected in communications and that didn't do anything so I out the setting back.
I went to control panel and sound, everything looked fine.

I did try another pair of headphones (which are breaking, only one ear works) and everything works perfectly but my other ones aren't working so well.

My tablet is updated to Windows 10, but its never been an issue. (still just stating which windows its in just in case)

Is this a glitch or are my headphones just dying?

EDIT: Ran a complete scan on Windows Defender, came up clean.

Comment: Your headphone cable might have broken.

Comment: Does your headphone play on low volume on another device too? Also, note that speakers can have different volume settings than the headphone jack.

Comment: They sound echoey and kind of fuzzy on my MP3. I've ridden in a car with them on 18 volume (MP3) which was plenty. Now, after testing in a silent room, it sounds much lower and definitely not as good as before.

Comment: I think Joey is right, I moved the wire and heard a small staticy sound.

Answer (score 0):

> I did try another pair of headphones (which are breaking, only one ear works) and everything works perfectly but my other ones aren't working so well.

You have a hardware problem at the headphones that are "low" (evidently you also have a hardware problem with the set that are not working on one ear.) It's not a software problem if other hardware works at correct volume.

Comment: I just plugged them in to my MP3 and the sound is very echoey and sort of fuzzy, nothing like it was before.

Comment: Got an ohm-meter or multimeter? Take readings between the sleeve of the pin (the part farthest from the tip) and the tip, and also from the sleeve to the ring.